# SCSS: How to concatenate rules with the same style?

Tags: sass

This SCSS code

```
@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .style-#{$i} { 
  position: relative;
  }
}
```

generates such CSS output:

```
.style-1 {
  position: relative;
}    

.style-2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

And I want it to be such:

```
.style-1, .style-2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

How to do it **using a cycle** in SCSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [placeholder selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) to group rules.

> Sass supports a special type of selector called a “placeholder
>   selector”. These look like class and id selectors, except the # or .
>   is replaced by %. They’re meant to be used with the @extend directive.
>   On their own, without any use of @extend, rulesets that use
>   placeholder selectors will not be rendered to CSS.

Sassmeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d0b0c71611e018e53d0477d668502283).

Scss:

```
%common {
  position: relative;
}

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .style-#{$i} { 
    @extend %common;
  }
}
```

Css output:

```
.style-1, .style-2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach, but you can accomplish this with a SASS list:

```
/* SASS Input */    
$numbers: "1","2","3","4","5";
$selector: ();

@each $num in $numbers {
    $selector: append($selector, unquote('.style-#{$num}'), 'comma');
}

#{$selector} {
  position:relative;
}

/* CSS Output */
.style-1, .style-2, .style-3, .style-4, .style-5 {
    position: relative;
}
```